Cannot import name 'EncoderDecoderCache' from 'transformers'
When I was run the train-4stage.sh file in LLaVolta's repo, I found it report the error Cannot import name 'EncoderDecoderCache' from 'transformers'.
The traceback is like:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/data/shika/miniconda3/envs/llavolta/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py", line 1364, in _get_module
    return importlib.import_module("." + module_name, self.__name__)
  File "/home/data/shika/miniconda3/envs/llavolta/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/data/shika/miniconda3/envs/llavolta/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py", line 190, in <module>
    from peft import PeftModel
  File "/home/data/shika/miniconda3/envs/llavolta/lib/python3.10/site-packages/peft/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .auto import (
  File "/home/data/shika/miniconda3/envs/llavolta/lib/python3.10/site-packages/peft/auto.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .mapping import MODEL_TYPE_TO_PEFT_MODEL_MAPPING
  File "/home/data/shika/miniconda3/envs/llavolta/lib/python3.10/site-packages/peft/mapping.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .mixed_model import PeftMixedModel
  File "/home/data/shika/miniconda3/envs/llavolta/lib/python3.10/site-packages/peft/mixed_model.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .peft_model import PeftModel
  File "/home/data/shika/miniconda3/envs/llavolta/lib/python3.10/site-packages/peft/peft_model.py", line 37, in <module>
    from transformers import Cache, DynamicCache, EncoderDecoderCache, PreTrainedModel
ImportError: cannot import name 'EncoderDecoderCache' from 'transformers' (/home/data/shika/miniconda3/envs/llavolta/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/__init__.py)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/data/shika/LLaVolta/llava/train/train_mem.py", line 1, in <module>
    from train import train
  File "/home/data/shika/LLaVolta/llava/train/train.py", line 32, in <module>
    from llava.train.llava_trainer import LLaVATrainer
  File "/home/data/shika/LLaVolta/llava/train/llava_trainer.py", line 7, in <module>
    from transformers import Trainer
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1075, in _handle_fromlist
  File "/home/data/shika/miniconda3/envs/llavolta/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py", line 1354, in __getattr__
    module = self._get_module(self._class_to_module[name])
  File "/home/data/shika/miniconda3/envs/llavolta/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py", line 1366, in _get_module
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.trainer because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
cannot import name 'EncoderDecoderCache' from 'transformers' (/home/data/shika/miniconda3/envs/llavolta/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/__init__.py)

Here's the .sh file I run (originally from LLaVolta's repo):
# export WANDB_API_KEY=''
# export WANDB_PROJECT=''
# export WANDB_ENTITY=''

ROOT_DATA='/home/data/shika/LLaVA/playground/data'
ROOT_WEIGHT='/home/data/shika/LLaVolta/checkpoint'
ROOT_LOG='/home/data/shika/LLaVolta/log'

LAYERS=2,2,16,0
STRIDES=8,2,2,1
PIVOTS=1300,2600,3900
GROUPING=avgpool1d
PROGRESSIVE=True
NAME=4stage

# pretrain
/home/data/shika/miniconda3/envs/llavolta/bin/deepspeed llava/train/train_mem.py \
    --deepspeed ./scripts/zero2.json \
    --model_name_or_path lmsys/vicuna-7b-v1.5 \
    --version plain \
    --data_path $ROOT_DATA/LLaVA-Pretrain/blip_laion_cc_sbu_558k.json \
    --image_folder $ROOT_DATA/LLaVA-Pretrain/images \
    --vision_tower openai/clip-vit-large-patch14-336 \
    --mm_projector_type mlp2x_gelu \
    --tune_mm_mlp_adapter True \
    --mm_vision_select_layer -2 \
    --mm_use_im_start_end False \
    --mm_use_im_patch_token False \
    --bf16 True \
    --output_dir $ROOT_WEIGHT/llava-v1.5-7b-pretrain-$NAME \
    --num_train_epochs 1 \
    --per_device_train_batch_size 1 \
    --per_device_eval_batch_size 1 \
    --gradient_accumulation_steps 1 \
    --evaluation_strategy "no" \
    --save_strategy "steps" \
    --save_steps 24000 \
    --save_total_limit 1 \
    --learning_rate 1e-3 \
    --weight_decay 0. \
    --warmup_ratio 0.03 \
    --lr_scheduler_type "cosine" \
    --logging_steps 1 \
    --tf32 True \
    --model_max_length 2048 \
    --gradient_checkpointing True \
    --dataloader_num_workers 4 \
    --lazy_preprocess True \
    --report_to wandb \
    --run_name $NAME-pretrain \
    # > $ROOT_LOG/llava-v1.5-7b-pretrain.out 2>$ROOT_LOG/llava-v1.5-7b-pretrain.err

# finetune
/home/data/shika/miniconda3/envs/llavolta/bin/deepspeed llava/train/train_mem.py \
    --deepspeed ./scripts/zero3.json \
    --model_name_or_path lmsys/vicuna-7b-v1.5 \
    --version v1 \
    --data_path $ROOT_DATA/LLaVA-Tuning/llava_v1_5_mix665k.json \
    --image_folder $ROOT_DATA/LLaVA-Tuning \
    --vision_tower openai/clip-vit-large-patch14-336 \
    --pretrain_mm_mlp_adapter $ROOT_WEIGHT/llava-v1.5-7b-pretrain-$NAME/mm_projector.bin \
    --mm_projector_type mlp2x_gelu \
    --mm_vision_select_layer -2 \
    --mm_use_im_start_end False \
    --mm_use_im_patch_token False \
    --image_aspect_ratio pad \
    --group_by_modality_length True \
    --bf16 True \
    --output_dir  $ROOT_WEIGHT/llava-v1.5-7b-$NAME \
    --num_train_epochs 1 \
    --per_device_train_batch_size 1 \
    --per_device_eval_batch_size 1 \
    --gradient_accumulation_steps 1 \
    --evaluation_strategy "no" \
    --save_strategy "steps" \
    --save_steps 50000 \
    --save_total_limit 1 \
    --learning_rate 2e-5 \
    --weight_decay 0. \
    --warmup_ratio 0.03 \
    --lr_scheduler_type "cosine" \
    --logging_steps 1 \
    --tf32 True \
    --model_max_length 2048 \
    --gradient_checkpointing True \
    --dataloader_num_workers 4 \
    --lazy_preprocess True \
    --report_to wandb \
    --run_name $NAME \
    --strides $STRIDES \
    --layers $LAYERS \
    --pivots $PIVOTS \
    --grouping $GROUPING \
    --progressive $PROGRESSIVE \
    # > $ROOT_LOG/$NAME.out 2>$ROOT_LOG/$NAME.err

I try to change the transformers version, but the project requires transfromers==4.37.2. And I try to change the peft version to 0.14.0, 0.11.0, 0.4.0, which didn't work.
What can I try next?

https://github.com/AiuniAI/Unique3D/issues/123

It's easy to solve by running the above command:
pip install peft==0.10.0

Specifically, when you ran the LLaVolta, you should make sure that the packages must be peft==0.10.0 and transformers==4.37.2.
